# How do I make my textures show up in render?

Tags: rendering, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I have only dragged pictures onto my objects for my animation and I'm guessing thats what the problem is. It shows up fine in edit mode or whatever but when i go to render it, it is completely white. Could someone please look at my file and tell me what I did wrong and how to fix it? http://pasteall.org/blend/31117

Comment: You need to add a material.

Comment: This looks like more confusion because Blender Internal allows us to drag and drop textures from the HD onto the model for display.  It creates the impression that a material already exists for the model.

Answer (score 1):

You've created a world texture, but I think you want a material texture.

To add a texture to a object, you must first create a material:

1. With the moon object selected, press *new* in *Properties > Material*:

   [image]
2. Now you can assign the texture you already created to your object, by selecting it in the texture panel, making sure that the middle option (checkered ball icon) is selected:

   [image]